# Consistency of Lasso(Cor 6.1 in Buhlmann and van De Geer): Problem with bounding l1 norm

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

Source: Statistics for High Dimensional Data by Buhlmann and van De Geer

We have a linear model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$, where the true parameter is $\beta^0$ and $\hat{\beta}$ is the lasso estimator.

We have the following inequality: $\lVert X(\hat{\beta}-\beta^0) \rVert_2^2 /n + \lambda \lVert \hat{\beta}_1 \rVert_1 \leq 2\epsilon^T X(\hat{\beta}-\beta^0)/n + \lambda \lVert \beta^0 \rVert_1$.

And then we bound $\left|2\epsilon^T X(\hat{\beta}-\beta^0)/n \right| \leq \max_j (2\left| \epsilon^T X^{(j)} \right|/n) \lVert \hat{\beta} - \beta^0 \rVert_1$.

Say $\max 2\left| \epsilon^T X^{(j)} \right|/n \leq \lambda_0$ where $\lambda \geq 2\lambda_0$.

Cor 6.1 basically says that in this case, $2\lVert X(\hat{\beta}-\beta^0) \rVert^2_2/n \leq 3\lambda\lVert \beta^0 \rVert_1$.

But I do not understand this conclusion.

It seems I can bound $\lVert X(\hat{\beta}-\beta^0) \rVert_2^2 /n \leq \frac{1}{2} \lambda \lVert \hat{\beta} - \beta^0 \rVert_0 + \lambda \lVert \beta^0 \rVert_1 - \lambda \lVert \hat{\beta} \rVert_1$, but I do not see how RHS turns into $3\lambda\lVert \beta^0 \rVert_1$.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*Bühlmann, Peter; van de Geer, Sara*, [**Statistics for high-dimensional data. Methods, theory and applications.**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-20192-9), Springer Series in Statistics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-20191-2/hbk). xvii, 556 p. (2011). [ZBL1273.62015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1273.62015).